# How to start making a wrapper for WebKit in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dll, webkit, dllimport

I don't want to use WebKit .NET because it doesn't have some functionality that I need and I know WebKit has, and I don't need all the functionality that WebKit .NET has. So I want to make my own wrapper with only the functions I need, that are not many. But I have no idea how to get started. I've used a little bit of p/invoke and called some native Win32 functions, so that much I know. But I don't know if I should place all the WebKit Dlls in the Windows/System folder and just start invoking functions as I would invoke Win32 native functions, or if I need to register those dlls somehow.

I really don't need specific advice for the WebKit, but on general, how to get started making a wrapper for any dll that doesn't come with Windows.

Comment: You may want to start by looking at the WebKit .Net source code for inspiration.

Comment: Is kinda huge, but yea I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/) is a great site with hundreds of examples of calling the win32 api.  You can call any dll using [DllImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to describe the function and the dll.  There's a lot of work to be done for big project though, so I don't know why you wouldn't start with WebKit.NET as a base and just add the missing functionality that you need.  The license is BSD so you can even integrate it into commercial products if you want...

Comment: Can you just put a dll, say, on your desktop and do a DllImport with the full file path?